# How to catch whether the item's __Security field is a modified publish

Tags: security, publishing

I want to share authority to read content with another system.
When contents are published to the public site, we create processing to output the data to the database.

Is there a way to catch only if you include a change in the `__Security` field?

It was possible to catch the item updated by the `item:saved` event.
I am in trouble because I do not know which field was changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `item:saving` event.

You can compare the original and the new item there, e.g.:

```
private static List<string> FindDifferences(Item newItem, Item originalItem)
{
    newItem.Fields.ReadAll();

    IEnumerable<string> fieldNames = newItem.Fields.Select(f => f.Name);

    return fieldNames
        .Where(fieldName => newItem[fieldName] != originalItem[fieldName])
        .ToList();
}

protected void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  Item newItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

  if (newItem == null || newItem.Database.DataManager.GetWorkflowInfo(newItem) == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  Item originalItem = 
    newItem.Database.GetItem(newItem.ID, newItem.Language, newItem.Version);

  var differences = FindDifferences(newItem, originalItem);

  // your code here
}
```

and register

```
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="item:saving">
      <handler type="My.Assembly.Namespace.MyEventHandler,
        My.Assembly" method="OnItemSaving" />
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```

Please be aware that in some cases saving of the item can be intercepted so not necessarily your changes will be saved.

Long time ago I wrote a blog post about tracking history of item changes https://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/sitecore/tracking-history-of-item-fields-changes-in-sitecore - I copied code from there.